# Lower bound for logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

Given a real $c$ such that $1 < c$, is there any known and direct lower bound, other than $0$, for $(\ln c)$, i.e., $A < \ln c$?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a lower bound with any special properties?  What makes a lower bound "direct"?

Comment: just a lower bound $A$ such that $0 < A$. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For all $x \ge 1$ we have $\log x \ge \frac{x-1}{x+1}$, with equality only at $x=1$.

Note that the derivative of $\log x$ is $1/x$, and the derivative of the rational function, which we can rewrite as $1 - 2(x+1)^{-1}$, is $2(x+1)^{-2}$:

$$ x \ge 1 \implies \frac{1}{x} \gt \frac{2}{(x+1)^2} $$

Comment: The lower bound can be "sharpened" to $2\frac{x-1}{x+1}$, giving an equal slope "osculation" at $x=1$, but the Question does not require this.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x\to 1}\ln x=0$, there can be no positive lower bound for the natural logarithms of numbers greater than $1$.

More explicitly, given $A>0$ you can always find $c>1$ such that $0<\ln c<A$: just take $c=e^{A/2}$.

Comment: While no constant $A$ is valid (as your argument shows), the OP is willing to take a rational function as the lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $\ln c \geq 0$ for $c \geq 1$, with equality only at $c=1$.

Comment: Except that the question said "other than $0$".  I'd guess he means some easily computed lower bound, for example maybe a rational function.

Comment: yes, this is what I'm requesting.

Comment: That's what the question says *now*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, there is no *constant* $A \gt 0$ as a lower limit for $\ln c$, $c \gt 1$.  However, you can use the approximation to $ln$ at 1, as given on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series), which starts $ln (1+x) \approx x - \dfrac{x^2}2\ldots$

Comment: Unfortunately this lower bound does not remain positive for long...

Comment: Since we were discussing bounds A "close to" 0, I assumed we were only interested in a bounding function for $x << 1$.